# how to clean this dataframe to use ggplot to plot a boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgOXq.jpg)

The data frame contains 8 colors and each color has 1000 values. I would like to use ggplot to plot boxplots with 8 boxes. But how to set x and y values in ggplot? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Since no sample dataset is provided, it's a little difficult to adjust so I provide a sample with 4 values and each of these colors have 1000 values.

```
library(tidyverse)
colorrs <- c("red","green","blue","orange")#load the 4 colors
colordata <- tibble::tibble(color = rep(colorrs, 1000),#make a tibble
               values = rnorm(4000))

#plot normally distributed values by color and adjust the colors 
colordata %>% 
  #Don't forget to set the aes values. X is first, y is second
   ggplot(aes(color,values,fill = color))+
   #geom_boxplot to create boxplots
   geom_boxplot()+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue","green","orange","red"))
```